# Why does the compiler tell me that no operators match the operand type in my 'if' and 'else if' statements?

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, encoding, operators

What is the problem in this code? I have been trying, but I don't know why I can't use `=` or `==` in the `if` statement.

```
#include <vector>

#include <cstdlib>

#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

/* I am trying to make the program output a periodic t symbol

so then it asks the user what the element is */

void symbols(std::vector<std::string> alcalinos) {

alcalinos = { "H", "Li", "Na", "K", "Rb", "Cs", "Fr" };

std::string elemento;

cout << "Introduce el elemento correspondiente al símbolo(en minusculas) : \n";

srand(time(NULL));

int random = rand() % 7;

cout << alcalinos[random];

cin >> elemento;

if ((alcalinos = "H") && (elemento = "hidrogeno")) {

    cout << "correcto\n";

}

else if ((alcalinos = "Li") && (elemento = "litio")) {

    cout << "correcto\n";

}

else if ((alcalinos = "Na") && (elemento = "sodio")) {

    cout << "correcto\n";

}

else if ((alcalinos = "K") && (elemento = "potasio")) {

    cout << "correcto\n";

}

else if ((alcalinos = "Rb") && (elemento = "rubidio")) {

    cout << "correcto\n";

}

else if ((alcalinos = "Cs") && (elemento = "cesio")) {

    cout << "correcto\n";

}

else if ((alcalinos = "Fr") && (elemento = "francio")) {

    cout << "correcto\n";

}

else {

    cout << "incorrecto\n";

}





int main(); {

    void symbols();

        

     }
```

Comment: You can't use `=` or `==` (`==` is correct) because `alcalinos` is a vector and you can't test if a vector equals a string.

Comment: The question is a perfectly reasonable question - but please be sure in future to format your code nicely; it'll not only help others, but also help you to find obvious silly mistakes.

Comment: Remember: one `=` for assignment, two for comparison: `==`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I must be in a good mood, I've added comments to indicate the errors you made

```
void symbols() { // no parameter for function

    // local declaration of vector instead of parameter
    std::vector<std::string> alcalinos = { "H", "Li", "Na", "K", "Rb", "Cs", "Fr" };

    std::string elemento;

    cout << "Introduce el elemento correspondiente al símbolo(en minusculas) : \n";


    int random = rand() % 7;

    cout << alcalinos[random];

    cin >> elemento;

    // compare alcalinos[random] not alcalinos
    // use == not =
    if ((alcalinos[random] == "H") && (elemento == "hidrogeno")) {  
        cout << "correcto\n";
    }
    else if ((alcalinos[random] == "Li") && (elemento == "litio")) {
        cout << "correcto\n";
    }
    else {
        cout << "incorrecto\n";
    }
} // missing }





int main() { // no ; after main()

    srand(time(NULL)); // seed RNG once in main

    symbols(); // no void before function call
}
```

When you are making this many mistakes, it means that you are trying to write too much code at once. When you are a beginner add your code literally one line at a time. And test the code after each line that you add. That way you are only trying to fix **one problem at a time**. You will find it much easier that way.

Comment: Thank you very much john. As you said i am a beginner and i was trying to make a cool program for learning periodic table at school, I didn't know i was making that many mistakes. I am surprised although it has only been a few days since i started learning, i'm actually 13 y old. I really aprecciate people like you helping beginers like me. Thanks for helping me.